# Primefaces autoComplete parameter of getAsString method Object is null inside of my converter

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am migrating from Icefaces selectInputText to Primefaces autoComplete component.

```
<ice:selectInputText styleClass="adminAppUserSelect"
                    id="searchUser" value="#{appUserData.selectedUserName }" rows="50"
                    width="100%" listVar="userList"
                    valueChangeListener="#{appUserData.updateListUser}"
                    binding="#{appUserData.userAutoComplete}"
                    title="#{msg.WEB_ADMIN_PAGES_APPUSER_AUTOCOMPLETE}"
                    listValue="#{appUserData.matchesListUser}">
                    <f:facet name="selectInputText" >
                        <ice:panelGrid  columns="3" width="400px" columnClasses="width20,width40,width40">
                            <ice:outputText 
                                value="#{userList.iappuserId}" />
                            <ice:outputText 
                                value="#{userList.cappuserName}" />
                            <ice:outputText 
                                value="#{userList.cappuserDesc}" />
                        </ice:panelGrid>
                    </f:facet>
                </ice:selectInputText>
```

I am using Primefaces 5.3.5 with JSF 2.2.8.
I see the same number of autocomplete result as my older version has in Icefaces 1.2 but I do not see user details. I see only number 0 in the first cell of each row.

```
<p:autoComplete id="searchUser" styleClass="adminAppUserSelect" value="#{appUserData.selectedUserName}"
                                maxResults="50" var="appUser" completeMethod="#{appUserData.completeUserList}"
                                binding="#{appUserData.userAutoComplete}" title="#{msg.WEB_ADMIN_PAGES_APPUSER_AUTOCOMPLETE}"
                                itemValue="#{appUser}" itemLabel="#{appUser.cappuserName}" converter="appUserConverter">
                    <!--<p:ajax event="itemSelect" listener="#{appUserData.updateListUser}"/>-->
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{appUser.iappuserId}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{appUser.cappuserName}" />
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column>
                        <h:outputText value="#{appUser.cappuserDesc}" />
                    </p:column>
                </p:autoComplete>
```

I am not sure about my converter that looks like

```
@FacesConverter("appUserConverter")
```

public class AppUserConverter implements Converter {

```
private int i;

@Override
public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String value) {
    ...
}

@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object object) {
    if(object == null)
        return null;
    else{
        return ((VAppuser) object).getCappuserName();
    }
}
```

}

[my result of autoComplete component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/47SKz.png)

Can you advise me, please what I made wrong?

**UPDATED:**
I see that value(data-item-value) is set properly but label(data-item-label) is not set yet.

**ADDED**
I noticed during debugging of my code that items

```
if(items != null) {
        for(Object item : items) {
```

are correctly assigned to list that got from completeMethod but ac.getItemValue() passes object that has null properties at this line

```
String value = converter == null ? (String) ac.getItemValue() : converter.getAsString(context, ac, ac.getItemValue());
```

in the Primefaces AutoCompleteRenderer.

Comment: I found out that this line returns number 0. Maybe this is cause that the output of autoComplete is 0 too.

I see that uic.suggestion has VAppuser object that I am looking for.

Comment: I see that value(data-item-value) is set properly but label(data-item-label) is not set yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by removing

```
<bean id="appUser" class="model.admin.usermgmnt.VAppuser"
      scope="session">
</bean>
```

from my application context as it was not necessary for the autoComplete component.